# Zipped variable losing value on 2nd iteration

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm pretty new to Python so I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way to code this. The problem I'm having is I have a 2nd For loop that runs inside another for loop. It works fine the first time, but on the second iteration, the second for loop doesn't register the data and skips over it so the it never runs again. I use a zipped tuple and it just looks like it loses the value completely. `

```
class Model:
    def predict(self, data):
         prediction = []
         distances = []
         for item in data:
             distances.clear()
             for trainedItem in self.Train_Data:
                 distances.append([(abs((item[0] - trainedItem[0][3])) + abs((item[1] - trainedItem[0][1])) + abs((item[2] - trainedItem[0][2])) + abs((item[3] - trainedItem[0][3]))), trainedItem[1]])
             distances.sort()
             targetNeighbors = []
             for closest in distances[:self.K]:
                 targetNeighbors.append(closest[1])
             prediction.append(Counter(targetNeighbors).most_common()[0][0])
         return prediction


class HardcodedClassifier:
     def fit(X_Train, Y_Train, k):
         Model.Train_Data = zip(X_Train, Y_Train)
         Model.K = k
         return Model`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator was depleted. Try `Model.Train_Data = list(zip(X_Train, Y_Train))` so it will iterate every time in the inner for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see, you are calling the Model class constructor instead of instantiating a model object and accessing its data. When you declare a class, the declaration only creates a constructor object. The constructor returns a new object of the type you defined when called.

```
class Bacon:
     tasty = true
     def __init__():
         self.salty = true

Bacon
>> <class constructor object at #memoryaddress>
Bacon.tasty
>> True
Bacon.salty
>> Error: Attribute not found

baconstrip = Bacon()
baconstrip
>> <Bacon object at #memoryaddress>

baconstrip.tasty
>> True
baconstrip.salty
>> True
```

The baconstrip object is of type Bacon and has memory and its own namespace allocated to it to store variables. The Bacon variable is the constructor, and you can also access it like an object too, but it's not an actual instance of itself.

For your code:

```
class HardcodedClassifier:
     def __init__(self, model):  # to initialize the class, provide a model.
         self.model = model

     def fit(X_Train, Y_Train, k):
         self.model.Train_Data = zip(X_Train, Y_Train)
         self.model.K = k
         # no need to return a value. The state of the object is preserved.

mymodel = Model()
myclassifier = HardcodedClassifier(mymodel)
```